# Heroku unable to find javascript files in FastAPI/React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, fastapi

I have an app with a FastAPI server and a React frontend in the same root folder. It builds and deploys to Heroku without any errors, and serves the FastAPI routes without error, but I'm getting a `404 NOT FOUND` error when trying to serve javascript and css files from my `client/build/static folder`.

In my `main.py` file I have the following code, which seems to be working as I expect:

```
# Construct the correct path to the "client/build" directory
static_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), "client/build")
# logging shows static_dir = /app/client/build

# Mount the static files from "client/build"
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory=static_dir), name="static")
```

When I run a heroku bash terminal, I can cd into my client build dir which has my `index.html` with expected src tags:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><title>MoodRaker</title><base href="/"/><script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.71b3f3e2.js"></script><link href="/static/css/main.e6c13ad2.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script></body></html>
```

Heroku logs look like this when I go to app root url:

```
2023-12-14T19:44:19.106578+00:00 app[web.1]: 98.59.132.14:0 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200
2023-12-14T19:44:19.107626+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=moodtracker-35756345a3ca.herokuapp.com request_id=cb46c81b-2de2-4e1c-b408-d54965e732b2 fwd="98.59.132.14" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2126ms status=200 bytes=1318 protocol=https
2023-12-14T19:44:19.280321+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.e6c13ad2.css" host=moodtracker-35756345a3ca.herokuapp.com request_id=5517735c-adc3-4bc4-a606-64201bfd30fa fwd="98.59.132.14" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=173 protocol=https
2023-12-14T19:44:19.273165+00:00 app[web.1]: 98.59.132.14:0 - "GET /js/main.71b3f3e2.js HTTP/1.1" 404
2023-12-14T19:44:19.278364+00:00 app[web.1]: 98.59.132.14:0 - "GET /css/main.e6c13ad2.css HTTP/1.1" 404
2023-12-14T19:44:19.273982+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.71b3f3e2.js" host=moodtracker-35756345a3ca.herokuapp.com request_id=1424389f-e890-4231-b158-67616f9549d3 fwd="98.59.132.14" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=173 protocol=https
2023-12-14T19:44:19.813433+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=moodtracker-35756345a3ca.herokuapp.com request_id=5977aef1-6d06-448c-a764-7fffb1f5c650 fwd="98.59.132.14" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=1318 protocol=https
2023-12-14T19:44:19.622001+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=moodtracker-35756345a3ca.herokuapp.com request_id=b7618d08-66e9-4eb5-b1b6-19f43f1af972 fwd="98.59.132.14" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=1318 protocol=https
2023-12-14T19:44:19.619219+00:00 app[web.1]: 98.59.132.14:0 - "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200
2023-12-14T19:44:19.812451+00:00 app[web.1]: 98.59.132.14:0 - "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 200
```

And if I navigate to this url `https://moodtracker-35756345a3ca.herokuapp.com/static/js/main.71b3f3e2.js` I get this response:

```
// 20231214104738
// https://moodtracker-35756345a3ca.herokuapp.com/static/js/main.71b3f3e2.js

{
  "detail": "Not Found"
}
```

Any idea what to try next?

I've tried rebuilding my react app and redeploying everything, which made no change.
At this point I'm just trying to get visibility into the issue. I've tried putting different url paths into the browser trying to access the javascript files that way (e.g. `https://moodtracker-35756345a3ca.herokuapp.com/js/main.71b3f3e2.js`), thinking maybe the path was not correct.

Everything works fine locally, and I've not been able to find any Heroku docs that address this issue.

Comment: Looking at your logs, it seems like the `/static` part of your URLs gets cut of before reaching your application. Is there maybe some nginx config (or other reverse proxy) that's stripping that drom the path?

Comment: I'm not using a reverse proxy. When I go to the networks tab and inspect the request, I can see it's making a GET request to `https://moodtracker-35756345a3ca.herokuapp.com/static/js/main.71b3f3e2.js` and getting a 404 response.
I can't figure out the difference between the two GET requests shown in the log, one for `heroku[router]` and the other for `app[web.1]`